# JSON Object Undefined (Nodejs)

Tags: json, node.js, api, express, request

I'm trying to access a JSON object but I'm getting errors while accessing the object. Could you please go through the code and let me know the mistake I'm making.

I'm writing 2 different cases to give a better understanding about my problem

Here's the JSON data:

[image: JSON DATA]

**Case 1:**

If I just try to access the company_base object, I'm getting the Undefined value

```
if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
  console.log("Insurance name is.....");
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(parsedData["company_base"]);
  }
```

Result:
Insurance name is.....
undefined

**CASE 2:**

I'm attaching 2 images. One contains the JSON text and the other contains the error I'm getting while trying to access the JSON object.

//This is the Code I'm using to access the object

```
   if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
    console.log("Insurance name is.....");
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(parsedData["company_base"][""business_type"]);
   }
```

Insurance name is.....
C:\Users\Ebbie\Desktop\Misc\mean\udemy\the web developer bootcamp\IntroToApis\CSG\app.js:37
        console.log(parsedData["company_base"]["business_type"]);
                                              ^

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'business_type' of undefined
>       at Request._callback (C:\Users\Ebbie\Desktop\Misc\mean\udemy\the web developer bootcamp\IntroToApis\CSG\app.js:37:47)
>       at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Ebbie\Desktop\Misc\mean\udemy\the web developer bootcamp\IntroToApis\CSG\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at Request. (C:\Users\Ebbie\Desktop\Misc\mean\udemy\the web developer bootcamp\IntroToApis\CSG\node_modules\request\request.js:1081:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\Ebbie\Desktop\Misc\mean\udemy\the web developer bootcamp\IntroToApis\CSG\node_modules\request\request.js:1001:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning an array of objects.  parsedData["company_base"] is trying to access the company_base key on the array.

You would want something like this:

```
parsedData[0]["company_base"]
```

And..

```
parsedData[0]["company_base"][""business_type"]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please go through the code and let me know the mistake I'm making.

You are getting `undefined` because `parsedData` is an array of one element. Notice `[` at the beginning of the json data. Instead of using `parsedData["company_base"]` to get value, iterate over it.

```
'use strict';

let _ = require('lodash');

if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  let insuranceCompanies = JSON.parse(body);
  _.each(insuranceCompanies, (company) => {
    let companyBase = company.company_base;
    console.log('Insurance name is.....', companyBase.business_type);
  });
}
```

Since `company_base` and `business_type` are static keys, I am using dotted notation to its access value.