# Access value of array object NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I think I'm going crazy... I'm just trying to do some basic API learning for NodeJS and I've got this, which works fine and prints "United States Dollar" to console...

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){

  const url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
  https.get(url, function(response){
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    response.on("data", function(data){
      const priceData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(priceData.bpi.USD.description);
    })
  })
```

but when I'm trying to access it by using the array position of USD (which is [0])like this...

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){

  const url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
  https.get(url, function(response){
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    response.on("data", function(data){
      const priceData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(priceData.bpi[0].description);
    })
  })
```

I get a crash of ...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
```

The JSON is

```
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Oct 21, 2021 16:10:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2021-10-21T16:10:00+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Oct 21, 2021 at 17:10 BST"
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  "chartName": "Bitcoin",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "symbol": "&#36;",
      "rate": "63,222.0050",
      "description": "United States Dollar",
      "rate_float": 63222.005
    },
    "GBP": {
      "code": "GBP",
      "symbol": "&pound;",
      "rate": "45,779.4964",
      "description": "British Pound Sterling",
      "rate_float": 45779.4964
    },
    "EUR": {
      "code": "EUR",
      "symbol": "&euro;",
      "rate": "54,306.7540",
      "description": "Euro",
      "rate_float": 54306.754
    }
  }
}
```

The USD object is position[0] of the bpi array (right?) so why can't I just tap into it like above? [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513740/json-object-undefined-nodejs) seems pretty similar to mine so can't see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: bpi contains an object, not an array, so position 0 doesn't exist, try with `BPI.USD.description`

Comment: thanks this was really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the content of `priceData.bpi` is not an array `[]`, it's an object `{}`, so you can't access `USD` by position, the only way to access it is `priceData.bpi.USD`.

More about JS [arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp), [objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

---

However, if you really need to access it by position, you can convert the contents of `priceData.bpi` into an array using the `Object.entries()` method.

**Example**

```js
let priceData = {"time":{"updated":"Oct 21, 2021 16:39:00 UTC","updatedISO":"2021-10-21T16:39:00+00:00","updateduk":"Oct 21, 2021 at 17:39 BST"},"disclaimer":"This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org","chartName":"Bitcoin","bpi":{"USD":{"code":"USD","symbol":"&#36;","rate":"63,340.4233","description":"United States Dollar","rate_float":63340.4233},"GBP":{"code":"GBP","symbol":"&pound;","rate":"45,865.2439","description":"British Pound Sterling","rate_float":45865.2439},"EUR":{"code":"EUR","symbol":"&euro;","rate":"54,408.4735","description":"Euro","rate_float":54408.4735}}}

let bpiArr = Object.entries(priceData.bpi)
console.log(bpiArr[0][1].description)
```

**Note:** the first `[0]` element of `bpiArr[0]` contains the string "USD" and the second `[1]` contains an object which got the description key and its value.

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: thanks this is awesome help

Comment: sorry didn't realise it ordered top to bottom in time order :-) - fixed now

Answer (score 1):

bpi is not an Array but an object. If it uses curly brackets it is an object. If using square brackets it is an array. To access the USD property of bpi object you use dot notation (like you have done: `bpi.USD`) or you use `bpi["USD"]`

Comment: thank you - and for the extra context about curly vs square brackets

Answer (score 1):

Based on your JSON **bpi** is an object but you are accessing it via array index which is wrong. If you want the value of USD, the way you were accessing in the first snippet is correct. However, if you want to use it as an array, you can do like below:

```
const {bpi= {}} = json;
const bpiArr = Object.entries(bpi);

// to access all the values
for (const [key,val] of bpiArr) {
   console.log(key,val.description)
}
```

Comment: thanks this was very helpful for me